# Arc length parameterization

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $C$ is some curve in 3-space and $P$ is some point on $C$. What does it mean for $r(s), c \le s\le d$ to be an arc length parameterization of $C$ with reference point $P$.

Continuing on with this:

Let $a$ and $c$ be some nonzero constants. The graph of $r(t) = a\cos(t)i+a\sin(t)j+ctk, 0\le t<\infty $ is a circular helix. Find an arc length parameterization of this helix with the reference point $(a,0,0)$.

Is this a suitable Solution:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Arc length parameterization means that the coordinates of the curve are $(x(f(s)), y(f(s)), z(f(s))$ such that if $s$ changes by an amount $t$, then the point on the curve moves by a distance that is linear in $t$.

Comment: You can define a length of the curve on $[c,s]$ as the variation of the curve, this is a continuous non increasing function $v$ that takes values in $[0,L]$ where $L$ is the total variation of the curve. Then define the reparameterised curve $\phi(v(s)) = f(s)$ for $s \in [c,d]$. It takes a little work to show that this is well defined and the variation of $\phi$ on $[0,t]$ (with $t \le L$) is $t$. If the arc length parameterization is smooth, then the derivative of the the curve has norm 1.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Do you mean: (x(r(s))?

Comment: @Tracy  Yes, $x(r(s)), ...$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork So how do I do the second part exactly

Comment: The parameterization of a unit circle (in a plane) is particularly simple:  $(x(s),y(s)) = (Cos(s),Sin(s))$.  See why?  As $s$ increases by a value $1.0$, then the arc length also increases by $1.0$.  (If $s$ increases by $2 \pi$, then so does the arc length--a full rotation--and so forth.)  In a helix, there is an added distance in each revolution, due to the progression along the perpendicular $z$ axis.  Try to figure out that "extra" factor and scale your parameterization accordingly.  (Hope this helps.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Can you check the solution I posted. Is it what the question is asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dr}{dt} = -a\sin t \, \hat i + a \cos t\,  \hat j + c\,\hat k $$ and $$\Big|\frac{dr}{dt}\Big|^2 = a^2 + c^2$$ for $s$ to be an arc length we need $$\Big| \frac{dr}{ds} \Big|^2 = 1 = \Big| \frac{dr}{dt}\Big|^2 /\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2$$ that means $$ \frac{ds}{dt} = \sqrt{a^2 + c^2} \to s = t\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}$$

Comment: Is the solution I posted correct?

Comment: @tracy, don't you need to set $t_0 = 0$ so that it matches the initial condition.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: @tracy, my mistake. i don't understand the meaning of $t_0$ in your answer. what value of correspond to the value of $t = 0?$

Comment: Just regard it as t